# How to measure percentages of colored areas over background? ImageJ?

Tags: image-processing, imagej

I would like to measure the percentage of purple area of this gray map.

[image]

I can say roughly speaking that represents the 10% of the area, but I need an exact value.

I know there is a free tool called ImageJ but I don't know how to use it.

Maybe you can suggest me another tool or how to perform such task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can't really be done; the purple on the map _isn't indicating area_; they are _dots_ indicating a _presence_. The size of the dots does not correspond to the amount of area taken up by that presence; all the dots are the same size. Just think: you will get _vastly_ different results if the same map was simply plotted out with _smaller dots._

Comment: Yes, I get it, but at least I could get some rough info by doing so.

Comment: Not really; the map was only ever meant to show distribution, not area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a small ImageJ plugin for that task:

```
import ij.gui.DialogListener;
import ij.gui.GenericDialog;
import ij.plugin.filter.ExtendedPlugInFilter;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilterRunner;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Purple_Counter implements ExtendedPlugInFilter, DialogListener{
    private final int FLAGS = DOES_RGB | PARALLELIZE_STACKS;
    private boolean preview = true;
    private ImagePlus im;
    private int count;
    private double total;
    private int color = 0xff64318a;
    private int background = 0xffd7d7d7;
    private double maxDistanceColor;
    private double maxDistanceBckg ;

    public int setup(String args, ImagePlus im){
        this.im = im;
        maxDistanceColor = 60;
        maxDistanceBckg = 60;
        return FLAGS;
    }

    public void run(ImageProcessor ip){
        int height = ip.getHeight();
        int width = ip.getWidth();
        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a < height; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < height; b++){
                int p = ip.getPixel(a,b);
                if ( calculateDistance(p,color) < maxDistanceColor){
                    count++;
                    ip.putPixel(a,b,0xffff0000);
                }
                if ( calculateDistance(p,background) < maxDistanceBckg){
                    total++;
                    ip.putPixel(a,b,0xff000000);
                }
            }
        }
        IJ.log("Counted: " + count + "| Total: " + total);
        IJ.log("Percentage: " +  (count/total) * 100f);
        IJ.log("");
    }

    private double calculateDistance(int color1, int color2){
        int red1 = (color1 >> 16)&0xff;
        int red2 = (color2 >> 16)&0xff;
        int green1 = (color1 >> 8)&0xff;
        int green2 = (color2 >> 8)&0xff;
        int blue1 = color1 & 0xff;
        int blue2 = color2 & 0xff;
        double distance = Math.sqrt((red1 * red1 - 2*red1*red2 + red2*red2) + (green1 * green1 - 2*green1*green2 + green2*green2) + (blue1 * blue1 - 2*blue1*blue2 + blue2*blue2));
        return distance;
    }

    public int showDialog(ImagePlus imp, String Command, PlugInFilterRunner pfr){
        //Dialog to control the used color distances
        GenericDialog gd = new GenericDialog("Distance Settings");
        gd.addMessage("Please chose maximal distances to identify POI and background pixels: ");
        gd.addSlider("POI Red: ", 0,255,0x64);
        gd.addSlider("POI Green: ", 0,255,0x31);
        gd.addSlider("POI Blue: ", 0,255,0x8a);
        gd.addSlider("BCKG Red: ", 0,255,0xd7);
        gd.addSlider("BCKG Green: ", 0,255,0xd7);
        gd.addSlider("BCKG Blue: ", 0,255,0xd7);
        gd.addSlider("POI max. Distance: ", 0.001, 1000, maxDistanceColor);
        gd.addSlider("BCKG max. Distance: ", 0.001, 1000, maxDistanceBckg);
        gd.addPreviewCheckbox(pfr, "Preview");
        gd.addDialogListener(this);
        gd.showDialog();

        if(gd.wasCanceled() ||!dialogItemChanged(gd, null)){
            return DONE;
        }
        return IJ.setupDialog(imp, FLAGS);
    }

    public boolean dialogItemChanged(GenericDialog gd, AWTEvent e){
        int alpha = 0xff;
        int colorRed = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
        int colorGreen = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
        int colorBlue = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
        int bckgRed = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
        int bckgGreen = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
        int bckgBlue = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
        color = (alpha << 24 | colorRed << 16 | colorGreen << 8 | colorBlue);
        background = (alpha << 24 | bckgRed << 16 | bckgGreen << 8 | bckgBlue);
        maxDistanceColor = gd.getNextNumber();
        maxDistanceBckg = gd.getNextNumber();
        return true;
    }

    public void setNPasses(int nPasses){
        //Has to be implemented for ExtendedPlugInFilter
    }
}
```

This plugin will open the following dialog:
[image: Image of the dialog window with different sliders to specify the POI color, the background color and the used distances]

This dialog allows to set both the pixel of interest (POI) color as well as the background (bckg) color.Via setting the distances manually, one can decide what the plugin determines as POI or as background. 
The reference colors are as following:

POI:
[image: Image of the color]

Background:
[image: Image of the color]

To verify you are using the right distance settings, i recommend to use the preview function. While using that, ImageJ will color every pixel it considers as POI red, whilst every background pixel will be colored black. I got the following result using the settings given in the dialog:

[image: Processed version of the image given by the author of the question. Background pixels are colored black, whilst pixels of interest are colored red.]
[image: Image of the plugin output with the calculated percentage of POI pixels]

As you can see, due to the artifacting some of the white pixels are also considered as background. Also the text is considered as background, so i recommend to remove it before using the plugin. If get rid of it, the result slightly changes to around 4.2%.

Comment: That is amazing! Maybe you can help me with some references or books for reading and learning about calculating image distances?

Comment: The original image was on a PDF file, but with pixel quality still. https://www.habitatyvivienda.gob.ec/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2017/05/Informe-Pais-Ecuador-Enero-2016_vf.pdf page 18. Maybe exporting it to a EPS or something would help?

Comment: Don't worry, i updated my answer to include the calculation for the image distance. If you are still interested, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference under the section euclidian distance

Comment: To answer your second question: That will not help, the image is already artifacted in the pdf.

Comment: That is so nice! But, maybe would you like to recommend me some sources from which I can learn how does it work, for further deep learning?