# Binarized grayscale image contains too much noise

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, grayscale, hsv

I currently have a digital pathology image like this:

[image]

Firstly I turn the image into grayscale using the following codes:

```
img=imread('DigitalPathology8.png');
figure;
imshow(img)
hsv=rgb2hsv(img); 
s=hsv(:,:,2);
```

And I got this grayscale image:
[image]

While I try to binarize this grayscale image using the following codes:

```
bw = imbinarize(s,'global'); 
figure
subplot(2,1,1)
imshow(s)
subplot(2,1,2)
imshow(bw)
```

I got the image like this:
[image]
What's wrong with my codes? When I applied the same algorithm to other images like this:
[image]
I could get the binarized image which only blue cells are white and other cells including backgrounds are black. So I also expect the same result after I applying the same codes to the first image I mentioned.
Could someone please help me out?
[image]

Comment: You have few cells to detect, so the threshold selection algorithm doesn’t work as you want it. In any case, depending on the IHC stain to be more saturated than the Hematoxylin is not the best approach. Look into stain separation (Google for “color deconvolution”, which is a misnomer, but oh well).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Cris! But I still want to ask why it worked well on the second pathology image?

Comment: There are a lot more stained cells there. The threshold looks for a value that separates greyvalues in the image meaningfully. If there are too few stained cells, this process will pick a lower threshold so there are more white output pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use the `rgb2gray()`[(look here)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) for your conversion:

```
grey=rgb2gray(img)
```

This should get you something like this:

[image: Image converted to grayscale]

Instead of global thresholding, i would recommend more sophisticated methods such as [Otsu](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html), which will get you much better results:

[image: Thresholded image]

However, if you only want to extract the blue cells instead of a simple thresholded version of your image, you should use a totally different approach like MaxEntropy on the grayscale image. This will give you something like this:

[image: First image thresholded]

and this

[image: Second image thresholded]

This tresholding method does not seem to be included in matlab, but a [plugin can be found](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35158-thresholding-the-maximum-entropy).

You could also try a total different approach to detect the blue dots by thresholding based on [color similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#Euclidean):
With this approach you would set each pixel to white which has a color distance to the blue color which is smaller than a given threshold. This should give you something like this (red markings represent the foreground of the image):

Reference color: [image: Image of the reference color]

[image: Thresholding by color distance]

For this approach i took the RGB color (17.3,32.5,54.5) as reference color, my max distance was 210. If you have ImageJ, you can this approach interactivly, a while back i wrote a [plugin for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826680/how-to-measure-percentages-of-colored-areas-over-background-imagej/50828650#50828650).As you can see, this approach also detects wrong cells, which is caused by the high value for the distance and the choosen reference color. This errors may be minimized by selecting a more appropriate reference color and smaller distance values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply! But since I need to deal with even hundreds of images like this, I think using ImageJ maybe not a good idea?

Comment: ImageJ should be able to perform batch processing, but the approach ist simple enough to implement it anywhere else.

Comment: So using MATLAB should also achieve the same result by implementing this approach?

Comment: Yeah, you simply need to calculate the color distance between the respective pixel and your reference color and if the distance is below an arbitrary threshold, you set the pixel to white, otherwise you set it to black

Comment: Thank you! But how to determine the threshold?

Comment: And is there any automatic method to determine the reference color?